# is there any method should i use for trigger update?

Tags: mysql, trigger

I try to modify the syntax of SQL trigger to mysql trigger
[check 32:01 for reference] ][1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-Sw3FjH1EM&feature=youtu.be&list=PL0VHAkRIxGQ7RLUtxdA6CBlVLT_K3m4SC)

someone suggested me to use this syntax in mysql, however I got error in mysql.
[image: error in mysql]
`DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER ComputeTotaluPDATE 
BEFORE UPDATE ON tblcart 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.qty <= 0 THEN
        SET NEW.status = 'Cancelled';
    END IF;
END
DELIMITER ;`

By the way this function is working to me.

`CREATE 
    TRIGGER  ComputeTotaliNSERT
 BEFORE INSERT ON tblcart FOR EACH ROW 
    SET NEW.total = NEW.price * NEW.qty;`

`CREATE 
    TRIGGER  ComputeTotaluPDATE
 BEFORE UPDATE ON tblcart FOR EACH ROW 
    SET NEW.total = (NEW.price * NEW.qty) - NEW.discount;`

Comment: `... END // DELIMITER ; ...`

Comment: i am only grasping at straws, but select the tblcart  table on the left side and not the users. further after seleting there is a form for triggers,.